# Access AWS RDS from OpenVPN using Routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, openvpn

I have a RDS instance on my VPC which has `Public accessibility = No`

I have an OpenVPN Access Server on an EC2 instance. And I have configured two users:

1. First one using NAT on my OpenVPN AS to access my private networks. Using NAT, OpenVPN translate my IP, therefore when I connect to AWS RDS, I'm using a local VPC IP address. This one connects without problems to my RDS instance.
2. Second one uses Routing on my OpenVPN AS to access my private networks.  In this case, I use a VPN IP (different to the private IPs on my VPC). This one can not connect to my RDS instance. I think is because it doesn't resolve the DNS of the endpoint.

For example: VPC -> 172.24.0.0/16

1. First scenario is like I use: 172.24.1.10 (a local VPC IP) to connect to RDS.
2. Second scenario is like I use: 172.47.224.100 (an IP from my VPN) to connect to RDS.

Is it possible to access the RDS instance through the VPN using Routing (which is the second scenario)? And how to do it? Thanks.

**Update**

I just confirmed the following:

1. If use the first scenario, I can ping an EC2 instance using Private IP and Private DNS.
2. If I use the second scenario, I can ping using Private IP, but I can't ping using the Private DNS.

Comment: Hello, if you are able to connect to the network, you'll be able to connect to the RDS, check the ingress rules for the RDS instance. I suggest you create a jumpserver a connect to the jumpserver, then the RDS. This is the best approach, for me. Also, this could act as a SSH tunnel.

Comment: It's weird but I can't connect to RDS. I already gave access on my RDS Security Group to my VPN (routing scenario). As I put in the example, I gave access to: 172.47.224.100 to my RDS. But nothing.

Comment: Create a testing nano server and try to access that server, if you can't maybe the VPN is not well configured.

Comment: Thanks. I just confirmed the following. If I use the second scenario, I can ping a AWS EC2 using Private IP, but I can't ping using the Private DNS. If use the first scenario, I can ping using Private IP and Private DNS. I'll update my question to be clear for others.

Comment: If you can ping the EC2 DNS, you'll be able to reach the RDS.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, with scenario 1 it works but I want with scenario 2 (Routing).